# req is "undefined" in one middleware and not in another

Tags: node.js, mern, multer, cloudinary, sharp

I am trying to use sharp in my MERN application, I sent a request from my frontend and it is undefined in my sharp middleware but if I get rid of the sharp middleware the req is defined later on. If I log the request in **createCountry**, the body is defined, if I log it in **convertToWebP**, it is not.

**the route is the one that says "/new" below:**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { storage } = require("../imageupload/cloudinary.js");
const multer = require("multer");
const {
  getCountry,
  createCountry,
  getCountries,
  updateCountry,
  deleteCountry,
  getAllCountries,
} = require("../controllers/country.js");
const {convertToWebP} = require('../middlewares/toWebP')
const { isLoggedIn, authorizeCountry, validateCountry } = require("../middlewares/auth");
const catchAsync = require("../utils/catchAsync");
const ExpressError = require("../utils/ExpressError");


const upload = multer({ storage: storage });



router.get("/", getCountries);
router.get('/getAll', getAllCountries);
router.post("/new", isLoggedIn, converToWebP, upload.array("images"), createCountry);
router.get("/:countryId", getCountry);
router.patch("/:countryId",  validateCountry, authorizeCountry, upload.array("images", 8), updateCountry);
router.delete("/:countryId",  authorizeCountry, deleteCountry);

module.exports = router;
```

**the code for create country is here:**

```
exports.createCountry = async (req, res) => {
  const { name, description, tags, location, cjLink } = req.body;
  const creator = req.user._id;
  const images = req.files.map((file) => {
    return { image: file.path, publicId: file.filename };
  });
  try {
    const geoData = await geocoder
      .forwardGeocode({
        query: req.body.location,
        limit: 1,
      })
      .send();
    const geometry = geoData.body.features[0].geometry;  
    const country = new Country({
      name,
      description,
      tags,
      creator,
      location, //: //geometry
      geometry,
      url: '',
      cjLink: cjLink,
    });
    const overall = new Overall({
      name,
      description,
      tags,
      creator,
      location, //: //geometry
      geometry,
      url: '',
      cjLink: cjLink,
    });
    country.images.push(...images);
    country.headerImage.push(...images);
    const data = await country.save();
    overall.url = `/country/${data._id}`
    data.url = `/country/${data._id}`
    overall.save();
    data.save();
    return res.status(201).json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    return console.log("error during create country", error);
  }
};
```

**And lastly the code for the convertToWebP is here:**

```
const sharp = require("sharp");
const { cloudinary } = require("../imageupload/cloudinary");

exports.convertToWebP = async (req, res, next) => {

    try {
      req.files = await Promise.all(req.files.map(async (file) => {
        const buffer = await sharp(file.buffer)
          .toFormat('webp')
          .toBuffer();
        return { ...file, buffer, originalname: `${file.originalname}.webp` };
      }));
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
  };
```

Any help is appreciated! I tried console.log as described above, I tried to change the order of the middleware and that does not work either, and I tried logging the req.body directly from the route and it came up as an empty object

Answer (score 0):

You cannot acces `req.files` before you use `multer` middleware

You have to reorder

```
router.post("/new", isLoggedIn, upload.array("images"), converToWebP, createCountry);
```